# The @NoRepositoryBean usage

Tags: spring

To add more methods to an existing Spring Data JPA interface without changing its original code, I am told to use the @NoRepositoryBean annotation. I don't know why it is needed or what is the difference between the following two approaches if I only need one repository instance of the entity Foo.

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {...}

@Repository
public interface FooExtendedRepository extends FooRepository {...}
```

and

```
@NoRepositoryBean 
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {...}

@Repository
public interface FooExtendedRepository extends FooRepository {...}
```

Comment: `@Repository` annotation does not make any sense in `spring-data` context, you may definitely omit it, the purpose of `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation is perfectly described in javadoc: "This will typically be used when providing an extended base interface for all repositories in combination with a custom repository base class to implement methods declared in that intermediate interface. In this case you typically derive your concrete repository interfaces from the intermediate one but don't want to create a Spring bean for the intermediate interface."